# ZF2, I18n and dynamic locale not working anymore after update

Tags: php, dynamic, zend-framework2, locale, zend-translate

After finally updating Apache 2.2 -> 2.4 and php 5.4 -> 5.5 translation in view is not dynamic anymore. My app is bilingual with english as fallback.
The locale is set i.e. by user's profile using ::onBootstrap

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap($events)
    {

```
    $translator = $events->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get(
        'translator'
    );

    $authSvc = $events->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService');

    $locale = $this->getLocale($authService);

    $translator->setLocale(
        \Locale::acceptFromHttp($locale)
    );

}
```

After updating Apache and php, translation still works but translation in view uses the default locale from the system. If I put the locale in $this->translate('MY TXT', *NAMESPACE*, 'en_US') it works but this is not the point. Even after debugging, I could not identify the source of the problem. It worked the way it suppose to do more than 2 years before. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. You have to set translator with locale to the view helper:

```
public function onBootstrap($events)
{

    ....
    $viewRenderer = $events->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ViewRenderer');

    $plugIn = $viewRenderer->plugin('translate');
    $plugIn->setTranslator($translator, __NAMESPACE__);
    ...
}
```

Otherwise the locale is taken from the config.global if set there (as in my case). No idea why it worked before for so long...